# Como agregar una columna nueva a un data frame?

Tags: r

Hola alguien sabe como agregar una columna nueva a un data frame?

```
DF <- data.frame (predictor=c ("a", "a", "b", "b"), respuesta=c (13.5, 0, 2.6, 4.1))
```

Comment: Y que hacer si la columna que queremos añadir tiene menos elementos que el dataframe?
osea, el dataframe tiene 1800 y mi nueva columna 181, me tira un error pero no se como aöadirle los NAs

Answer (score 3):

Hay varias formas de agregar columnas nuevas. Algunas de ellas son:

Agregarlas al momento de crear el `data.frame`:

```
DF <- data.frame (predictor=c ("a", "a", "b", "b"), respuesta=c (13.5, 0, 2.6, 4.1),
                  ColNueva=rnorm(4))
```

Si el objeto ya está creado:

```
DF[,3] <- rnorm(4)
DF$ColNueva<- rnorm(4)
DF<- data.frame(DF, ColNueva=rnorm(4))
cbind(DF, ColNueva=rnorm(4))
```

Para una futura pregunta deberías especificar cual es el output que quisieras.

Comment: Perfecto! muchisimas gracias! pego entonces el script que este armando directamente